# gcloud auth activate-service-account logout / revoke / remove / unset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I,ve added my service-account successfuly using below command.

> gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=mycredentialsialreadyhad.json

Now I can't remove or logout from it.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
i tried this commands and got error

> 1. gcloud auth revoke
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.auth.revoke) Cannot revoke GCE-provided credentials.
>
> 2. gcloud config configurations delete default
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.config.configurations.delete) Deleting named configuration failed because configuration [default] is set as active.  Use `gcloud config configurations activate` to change the active configuration.

edit2: this gcloud cli is on GCP ubuntu VM

Comment: If your code/application/cli is running on a GCP instance, you cannot revoke the service account assigned to your Compute engine instance. The credentials for that service account derive from metadata. Google creates those credentials. You cannot revoke/cancel them as they are "created' for compute services. Note: you cannot deletes/void/cancel the default service account. Those keys are private to Google and not to your instance/application/cli.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## UPDATE

Use a command with a specified account because you can't revoke the Compute Engine service account(**default**).

For example:

```
gcloud auth revoke serviceaccount@testproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

and run:

```
gcloud auth list
```

It should only display the default service account of the Compute Engine:

> [PROJECT-NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: both commands gives the same error `ERROR: (gcloud.auth.revoke) Cannot revoke GCE-provided credentials.`

Comment: when i use `gcloud auth list` i can only see one account and that is not the account i added.the other thing is when try to access cloud sorage before add service_account it showed permission error.after i add the service account it worked perfectly.but after `gcloud auth revoke serviceaccount@testproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` it still have permission to storage.does VM's have full access to cloud ?? if so why does it show permission error in the first place??.thanks for  the answer.

Comment: If you no longer see the added service account inside your vm, it might be revoked or deleted in your vm. If you want to delete the added or custom service account, go to IAM or Access > IAM, tick the checkbox of your added service account then click **Remove** to remove the access and fully remove it to your project.

Comment: thanks for help john.i've mix-up  _defoult account_ with  _service account_  i've added later.

Answer (score 9):

I may be late to the party on this, but the solution that I found works is:

```
gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account
```

Followed by:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR; To logout from all accounts**

```
gcloud auth revoke --all
```

To check active account logins

```
gcloud auth list
```

To logout form one account only (take account from command above)

```
gcloud auth revoke [ACCOUNT]
```

Comment: Does this permanently revoke the service account or just log it out?

Comment: As I understood from the [doku|https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke] it revokes the token from server and credential from local host, so logs out only, if you want to revoke permanently you need to go with gcloud iam service-accounts keys delete or something a'like

Answer (score 2):

this error happens when you try to remove a service account that was propagated to the machine during the creation time ([docs here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--service-account)).
this service account could not be removed from your machine.

in any other case, the following commands should work (as mentioned in other answers here).

```
gcloud auth revoke --all
```

OR

```
gcloud auth revoke [ACCOUNT]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the  below syntax to activate the service account. Here we need to mention service account ID.
gcloud auth activate-service-account testpck@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=xxxxxx.json --project=xxxxxx

Use the below syntax to revoke the service account:
gcloud auth revoke testpck@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Error encountered in your case because the service account ID was not mentioned in **gcloud auth revoke** command , which is trying to revoke your active google account.

Permissions are denied if you disable the service account instead of revoke. If you revoke the service account then default account will get activated and that might have permission to storage.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `gcloud auth revoke` commands mentioned above, I also had to unset the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable.

```
unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I just do the following

step-1 : gcloud auth list

it gives you result like the follwoing

ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        test@testProj.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        test2@testProj.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        test3@testProj.iam.gserviceaccount.com
*       myOwnerMailid@gmail.com  --> * means its active

Step 2: gcloud config set account test3@testProj.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

now if you run again step-1 you can see your activated account